# C# Display a TextBox for a few seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am developing an application for Windows CE using Visual Studio 2008 where I need to display a TextBox for a few seconds like a "Success!" pop-up message you see in some programs.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int s;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (s == 1)
        {
            textBox1.Show();
            textBox1.Text = "Success!";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Show();
            textBox1.Text = "Try Again!";
        }

    }
}
```

Considering that I am using a .NET 3.5 Compact Framework which apparently does not support `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Any solution?

Comment: Use the [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class

Comment: Isn't it better to use `Messagebox.show("Sucess!");`?

Comment: The System.Windows.Forms.Timer is absolutely supported in .NET CF 3.5! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer_members(v=vs.90).aspx See all the little device icons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the [timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Provides a mechanism for executing a method at specified intervals.
>   This class cannot be inherited.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 1000;
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimerEvent);
```

> **Remark**:
>
> Use a TimerCallback delegate to specify the method you want the Timer
>   to execute. The timer delegate is specified when the timer is
>   constructed, and cannot be changed. The method does not execute on the
>   thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread
>   supplied by the system.